# DayJS last day of janurary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, dayjs

I am trying to set a date to the last day of January with DayJS.

```
const lastDay = dayjs('2014-01-31');
console.log(lastDay);
```

> "2014-01-30T23:00:00.000Z"

Why is it giving the 30. of January, and not the 31.? Looking at the [documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format), it says "Day of Month, 1 - 31". When I do

```
const lastDay = dayjs('2014-01-32');
console.log(lastDay);
```

I get the 31. as the day

> "2014-01-31T23:00:00.000Z"

Why is that?

Comment: i guess your timezone is +1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate the date in dayjs like this `dayjs('2014-01-31')` the input date is treated as UTC. So you need to specify the timezone of the input date. Dayjs has the plugin [timezone](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/timezone) which helps with this feature.

```js
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc);
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone);
const lastDay = dayjs('2014-01-31').tz('Europe/Paris', true).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(lastDay);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/timezone.js"></script>
```